# How to check if system restore/protection is enabled and set disk space usage using visual basic script

Tags: windows, vbscript, wmi

I am using the following visual basic script to enable system restore/protection in windows 10. It works successfully. However I first want to check if system protection is already enabled or not before doing so and I want to set disk space usage to 15% after enabling system protection. I have gone through the documentation on microsoft website carefully but I have not been able to find any clue about that. Does microsoft provides an interface to check if system protection is enabled and reserve disk space.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
  , WScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
   WScript.Quit
End If

Dim oSR
Set oSR = GetObject("winmgmts:
 {impersonationLevel=impersonate}!root/default:SystemRestore")
oSR.Enable("D:" & "\")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find what you need in the registry under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRestore
```

Some value are not populated by default.  I don't know this site policy to linking to other help sites, and I'm not into copy/pasting other's work.  So looking for "The Registry Keys and Values for the System Restore Utility" should provide you with the details you need.